# Advanced slicing. Higher order slicing/selecting

Tags: python, numpy

I'm confused about the semantics of numpy advanced slicing in some code I found in our codebase today. Let me start out with an example:

```
# example boolean matrix
a = np.random.rand(5, 5) > 0.5

# Outputs
array([[ True, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False]])
```

```
dim_1 = np.arange(5)
dim_1 = dim_1[:, None] # expand into ndarray :: (5,1)
dim_2 = np.eye(5,5).astype(int) # convert to ints so we can use as idx
a[dim_1, dim_2]

# Outputs
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

What we observe here is that `dim_2` is selecting values of `a`. In this example we see a[:,1] along the eye, and a[:,0] for the remaining entries.
 While I do understand the output, I don't undestand the semantics. What really confused me is first dim reshape into `(5,1)`. The result is quite different without the additional dimension. My understanding of advanced slicing is that you can use higher order `ndarray`'s to index into other `ndarray`'s, but only to select from the last dimension. To achieve higher order slicing you need to index into each dimension individually, which returns you a flat vector.

I think the method is quite neat but I am lack the understanding of how numpy is parsing this slice. Anyone got some insights?

Comment: The 2  indexing arrays are (5,1) and (5,5), which broadcast to (5,5).  Initialling `a` to `arange(25).reshape(5,5)` may make it easier to visualize the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a distinctive array:

```
In [13]: a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

In [14]: dim1 = np.arange(5)[:,None]
In [15]: dim2 = np.eye(5,5).astype(int)
```

Look at how these two arrays broadcast with each other:

```
In [16]: np.broadcast_arrays(dim1, dim2)
Out[16]: 
[array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]), 
 array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])]
```

The returned array matches these 2 in shape, with elements selected from `a` by pairing individual elements from each.

```
In [17]: a[dim1, dim2]
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  5,  5,  5],
       [10, 10, 11, 10, 10],
       [15, 15, 15, 16, 15],
       [20, 20, 20, 20, 21]])
```

For each row, as indexed by `dim1`, it picks an element from column 0 or 1 depending on the value of `dim2`:

```
In [21]: a[0, dim2[0,:]]
Out[21]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [22]: a[3, dim2[3,:]]
Out[22]: array([15, 15, 15, 16, 15])
```

If I change `dim2` to be a 'diagonal'

```
In [25]: dim2 = np.diag(np.arange(5))
In [26]: dim2
Out[26]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4]])
In [27]: a[dim1, dim2]
Out[27]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  5,  5,  5],
       [10, 10, 12, 10, 10],
       [15, 15, 15, 18, 15],
       [20, 20, 20, 20, 24]])
```

Now most values are `a[:,0]`, but the diagonals are `a[i,i]`.

This indexing isn't any different from indexing with 1d arrays, as in

```
In [28]: a[np.arange(5), np.arange(5)]
Out[28]: array([ 0,  6, 12, 18, 24])

a[0,0], a[1,1], a[2,2], ...
```

Another example that can be explained by broadcasting the two arrays against each other.  This selects all elements, the same as `a[:,:]` except it is a copy, not a view:

```
In [29]: a[np.arange(5)[:,None], np.arange(5)[None,:]]
Out[29]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Comment: Getting back to this took a while. Apologies. Thx a bunch for your reply. So if I get this right, the semantics of this is that if you index a `d`-dimensional ndarray with `d` ndarrays you can use the positional values as indicies. That's pretty neat! I'm however still confused about the use of higher order arrays for indexing. Is this described in the documentation anywhere?